Rendering gets triggered in the middle of a redux update
Are redux updates synchronous? Can we expect an entire update to complete before rendering code is triggered?
Let's say you have a middleware which catches an event from one redux store and updates a different redux store accordingly, to keep them in sync.
const MyMiddleware: Middleware = (store: MiddlewareAPI<AppDispatch, RootState>) => (next) => (action) => {
    console.log('MyMiddleware start');
    const result = next(action); // apply reducer1

    if (action.type === reducer1Types.SET_ACTIVE_WORKSPACE) {
        console.log(`MyMiddleware middle`);
        store.dispatch(reducer2Actions.initializeWorkspace(action.payload.workspace));
    }

    console.log(`MyMiddleware end`);
    return result;
};

However, for some reason, App.jsx#render function is invoked when reducer1 is already updated and reducer2 is not run. In the console, it would be
> MyMiddleware start
> <logging from App.jsx#render>
> MyMiddleware middle
> MyMiddleware end

Is this expected?
When I trace this code, I also see that it goes into rendering logic before exiting middleware:

The store setup:
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        reducer1: reducer1.reducer,
        reducer2: reducer2.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(MyMiddleware),
});


Do you have declared any of your middleware async? Also, do you have an incredibly good reason for two Redux stores? Redux is meant to be one store only.

(1) No  (2) Sorry, I meant reduxStore1 & 2 as reducers, not literal redux stores. I.e. configureStore(reducer: { reducer1, reducer2 }). I'll update the question.

In that case, you should have both reducers react to the same action, not dispatch another action. See the Redux Style guide: Allow Many Reducers to Respond to the Same Action

@phry Thanks! In that case, it's tricky, as each reducer can only see its own state. Because actions only contain minimal payload, it's hard to reason about modelReducer's data when handling a DELETE_ITEM or UPDATE_ITEM event in uiReducer. (reducer1 & reducer2) Middleware seems to offer a simple way to react to changes in one state slice (model) and generate side-effects in a different slice (ui).

It would solve the batching issue though, without the need for an explicit batch(() => {...}) call.

The problem is solved now, with the batch api, but I appreciate you looking into this!

Just needed to use the batch api. (Running React 16)
const MyMiddleware: Middleware = (store: MiddlewareAPI<AppDispatch, RootState>) => (next) => (action) => {
    let result = null;
    batch(() => {
        result = next(action);
        if (action.type === reducer1Types.SET_ACTIVE_WORKSPACE) {
            store.dispatch(reducer2Actions.initializeWorkspace(action.payload.workspace));
        }
    });
    return result;
};

Batching logic seems to be applied by default in some cases, but not others (more info).
